# Grid different order on smaller screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this order in my grid when it's a normal sized computer screen:

```
{1}{2}
{3}{4}
{5}{6}
```

When i make the screen smaller i want it to reorder, but it doesn't reorder correctly.

Actual:

```
{1}
{2}
{3}
{4}
{5}
{6}
```

Wanted:

```
{1}
{3}
{5}
{2}
{4}
{6}
```

What kind of CSS formatting do I have to use to achieve the wanted display of my elements.

Current CSS:

```css
.general {
  background-color: pink;
  order: 1;
}
.anonymous{
  background-color: aqua;
  order:4;
}
.dead{
  background-color: blue;
  order: 2;
}
.dead-and-archived {
  background-color: green;
  order:5;
}
.created {
  background-color: yellow;
  order:3;
}
.private {
  background-color: red;
  order:6;
}
```

Current HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="general col-sm-4" >
      General
    </div>
    <div class="anonymous col-md-8">
      Anonymous
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class=" dead col-md-4">
      Dead entities
    </div>
    <div class=" dead-and-archived col-md-8">
      Dead and archived
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="created col-md-4 ">
      Created entities
    </div>
    <div class="private col-md-8">
      private user repos
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add your code snippet here for better clarification and understanding...

Comment: Post the css you are using right now. Presumably you are floating the elements? If so, you may wish to put the 1, 3, 5 elements into their own container and the 2, 4 6, into another container then float those. That way, the 2, 4, 6 would go "under" the 1, 3, 5 one.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap or something else?

Comment: I am using bootstrap. Will post the css in a few minutes,

Comment: posted the code

Comment: I think you have to change html for this

Comment: @JoelSuter solution below

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is just change the way you put your content in divs. 
Unless your HTML is set in stone, the most obvious way to get what you want is to structure your HTML so that it facilitates what you want.

If you want

```
{{1},{4}}
{{2},{5}}
{{3},{6}}
```

You shouldn't do

```
{{1},{2}}
{{3},{4}}
{{5},{6}}
```

Change your html so that it looks like this at a structural level:

```
<div class="column">
    <div class="row">
        square 1
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        square 2
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        square 3
    </div>
</div>
<div class="column">
    ...
</div>
```

Now use CSS to give the columns a width so that they are next to eachother, and when you use a mobile device, the right one is placed under the left one.

The alternative way to do this is to add responsive css rules that apply absolute positioning, but really, that is just a nasty way to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will be helpful:
N.B. feel free to change the classes value according with your needs

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="col-xs-12">1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12">3</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12">5</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="col-xs-12">2</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12">4</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12">6</div>
    </div>

  </div>




</body>


</html>
```